# Array sorting and matching in Karate using JsonPath and karate.eval

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsonpath, karate

I am trying to validate whether a collection being returned is in alphabetical order.

There are two parts to this collection though, as the first six are sorted separately from the rest. e.g.

- **Bob**
- **Edith**
- **Egbert**
- **Nial**
- **Simone**
- **Sasha**
- Aaron
- Bertha
- Charlie
- etc.

I can hard code the first six using JsonPath and doing a simple match, but I am uncertain how to match the rest (there are lots, and the dataset can change).

This is my feature file:

```
Feature: Array should be sorted alphabetically, with the first important 6 sorted separately

  Background:
    * call read('common-config.feature')

  @wip
  Scenario: I request brand options by region
    Given url baseUrl
    And path '/importantEmployees'
    When method GET
    Then status 200

    # match first six
    And def importantSix = $..employees[0:6]
    And def importantSixNames = get importantSix[*].name
    And match importantSixNames == [ 'Bob', 'Edith', 'Egbert', 'Nial', 'Simone', 'Sasha' ]

    # match the rest to a sorted array
    And def otherPeople = $..employees[6:]
    And def otherPeopleNames = get otherPeople[*].name
    And eval
    """
    var sortedOtherPeopleNames = karate.get('otherPeopleNames').sort();
    karate.set('sortedOtherPeopleNames', sortedOtherPeopleNames);
    """
    And match otherPeopleNames == sortedOtherPeopleNames
```

I've tried following the example of using an eval call, but I can't get it to work.

https://github.com/intuit/karate#eval

EDIT: I have found out how to share variables between the Javascript and Karate Feature file. I need to use karate.get('varName') in the Javascript. The sorting is still an issue though. I've edited the feature file to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Karate now has a `karate.sort()` API that is very versatile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318045/143475

First, `eval` was introduced in `0.7.0` onwards, I apologize since the documentation is being revised. I recommend that you use version 0.7.0.RC4 which is available at the time of this post.

Great question ! I reckon this is a case where diving into Java makes sense. The good news is that you can do this 'as JS' itself. The code below uses the `eval` keyword, but if are not in a position to upgrade you should be able to figure out a way to use JS functions as you already know.

```
* def ArrayList = Java.type('java.util.ArrayList')
* def Collections = Java.type('java.util.Collections')

* def json = [{ v: 'C' }, { v: 'b' }, { v: 'A' }]
* def actual = $json[*].v
* print actual
* def list = new ArrayList()
* eval for(var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) list.add(actual[i])
* print list
* eval Collections.sort(list, java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
* print list
* match list != actual
* match list == ['A', 'b', 'C']
```

And here is the output of the 3 `print` statements:

```
21:59:34.211 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] [
  "C",
  "b",
  "A"
]

21:59:34.241 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] [
  "C",
  "b",
  "A"
]

21:59:34.273 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] [
  "A",
  "b",
  "C"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I also need case-insensitive search, so usually I'd pass the String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER comparator into the sort() method on Collections, but Karate doesn't seem to like it.


java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: Collections.sort(otherProviderNamesAsList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) ........

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined to java.util.Comparator

Comment: @matthewh86 edited my answer - just use `java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` and things are good.

Comment: Hi @ptrthomas how would this logic work for the array having floating values For example - [0.565345345, 0.3432432432, 1 , 0.8765465456, 0.565435433]

Comment: @PeterThomas two questions for you. 
Could the first eval be replaced by a copy line? 
How would one go about making this into a reusable feature ?

Comment: @Btuman I don't understand your first question. second answer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/sort-array.feature

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas, so what I was trying to set up was having a common feature file with a bunch of utilities. I would like to call a specific utlity scenario (that is more than just a java or Javascript function) and pull out the result. Is setting up tags the only way to achieve that?

Comment: @Btuman I don't understand. please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file - if that doesn't help, please ask a new / proper question and for goodness sakes, be clear (ideally with an example)

Comment: Thank you, will do.