# How to iterate through a nested array of objects in karate and also to sort it?

Tags: automation, karate

```
 Here goes my code:
{
"infolist": [
{
"id": 1,
"marketList":[
{"datevalue": "2020-03-01",
"year": "2020"
},
{
"datevalue": "2021-03-01",
"year": "2021"
}
]
},
{
"id": 2,
"marketList":[
{"datevalue": "2018-03-01",
"year": "2018"
},
{
"datevalue": "2020-03-01",
"year": "2020"
}
]
}
]
}
```

1. I want to sort this entire object which my response based on every datevalue field which is present in each marketList array of every object of the infoList array.

I understand that this json object is very nested.
But is there any way I can achieve this via karate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm focusing only on the array under `infoList` as a variable called `response`:

```
* def dates = $response[*].marketList[*]
* def sorted = karate.sort(dates, x => x.datevalue)
```

I'm assuming you just want all the dates since your question is not clear at all. For more hints refer this part of the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms

For `karate.sort()` refer to the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-sort

Here is an example to explain how it works. That `x` is a JS function argument. Take the help of someone who knows JS functions if needed:

```
* def foo = [{a: { b: 3 }}, {a: { b: 1 }}, {a: { b: 2 }}]
* def fun = function(x){ return x.a.b }
* def bar = karate.sort(foo, fun)
* match bar == [{a: { b: 1 }}, {a: { b: 2 }}, {a: { b: 3 }}]
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the solution. It worked for me. Can you tell me the logic behind this? I mean which sort is getting used here and how x is getting used? is x an iterator?

Comment: Also apologies for not accepting the answers previously. Wasnt aware about it.

Comment: @TriptiPaliwal I have edited the answer with more details