# How to use a variable inside a js function which is declared outside a js function in karate framework

Tags: automation, karate

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
I've declared one variable outside of js function in karate code. This variable is an array of objects and already consists of values.
I've written a js function inside of an eval tag and within that function there's a for loop that uses this array.

```
* def results  = response.results
* eval
"""
Var md;
for(var id in results){
md = results[id].data
console.log(md)
}
"""
```

But in console [object, Object] is getting printed. I'm assuming the for.loop is not able to understand the array name I want to loop on.`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is *never* to use a JS for loop in Karate. Refer to this section of the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#loops

Here's how I would do it:

```
* def response = { results: [1, 2, 3] }
* response.results.forEach(x => karate.log(x))
```

Work with someone who knows JS well if needed. Please assume that karate does not support the kind of JS you are doing. That has nothing to do with testing APIs.

Comment: Thanks Peter! But what if I want to do some more operations on that step where you have written karate.log(x). How can I do that? Suppose I need to get each array element and then apply some sorting on it. because my array is an array of objects. So I want o sort each object.

Comment: @TriptiPaliwal don't you already have a solution for sorting here ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318045/143475 - again, what you are asking for has nothing to do with testing APIs so maybe karate is the wrong tool for you. please also see my recommendations on how you should think about API tests instead of trying to create "smart" tests that will always land you in trouble (in my experience): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475